# What effect does dual wielding pistols have?

Tags: killing-floor

I like dual wielding pistols because it doesn't obscure the center of the screen, but my ability to inflict headshots seems to suffer. What exactly does having two pistols out at the same time do? Is there a hard accuracy penalty for dual wielding, or do I just need to learn to aim without iron sights? Are there any other obscure effects dual wielding provides?

Comment: There may still be a bug in the game that affects aiming when dual-wielding when facing a diagonal direction.  Basically, duel-wielding is impossible to aim, bug or no bug.  You should never dual wield as a sharpshooter - you'll be far more effective landing headshots consistently.

Comment: @jw013 well, I often get no-scope headshots, so if they aren't actually bugged or have a hard accuracy penalty then I reckon I could do pretty well with them.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [this thread](http://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/showthread.php?t=82390) - interesting info there.  It seems the bug I mentioned is still there.  For me, the reload time is another big downside.  Single pistol reloads are fast, and I do it whenever I get the slightest bit of downtime to keep my magazine as full as possible.  The reload time of dualies is so long that you rarely get enough time to do it safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Killing Floor wiki](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Dual-wield#Secondary_weapons):

> > There is a unique ability extended only to these four secondary weapons, which is that of dual wielding; the ability to carry and use two of any at the same time for doubled rate of fire. There are however various downsides to dual wielding; it doubles reload times, renders the iron sights useless making long range fire difficult, and doesn't increase the maximum ammo carried. It also takes up an additional 4 weight blocks with the 9mm's (because the standard 9mm pistol weighs nothing due to it being undroppable) and an extra 2 with the .44 Magnums and MK23, effectively meaning that two 9mm's, two .44 magnums, two MK23s, a single handcannon, and dual handcannons weigh the same amount.

There was a bug that caused the off-hand 9mm pistol to fire inaccurately depending on the direction the player was facing, however this has been fixed in [patch 1054](http://www.kf-wiki.com/wiki/List_of_2013_updates#Weapons_3).